# Low pressure Diesel pumping with High pressure Gasoline pump?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, pumps, hydraulics, diesel

We are in desperate search of suitable pumps for one of our applications.
We need to be able to pump Diesel fuel in a range going from 5bars to 125bars.

To do such thing, I've been looking at [Bosch HDP5](http://www.bosch.co.jp/tms2015/en/products/pdf/GS-Datenblatt_HDP5_EN_low.pdf) gasoline direct injection pump (and it's prop valve conveniently attached).

Ok now... two problems :

1. I have doubts about it's behaviour at low pressure (5bars)
2. It's a gasoline pump and we plan to pump diesel

Structurally, it's a piston pump and my limited understanding of it don't see where the problem could be in pumping lower pressure than it's max.

And as far as diesel fuel go, it's got a higher lubricity so I don't see it being a problem either...

But being far from an expert, I'd like to have your feedback on it.

- The other option would be to use a Bosch CP1 or CP3 which is a high
  pressure diesel pump.
  Now the fuel is right but the pressures involved are way higher than we need. The pressure compatibility question still stands...
- And the last option would be to use a simple External gear pump such
  as the [Bosch Rexroth](https://www.boschrexroth.com/en/xc/products/product-groups/industrial-hydraulics/pumps/external-gear-pumps) ones but also derating them a lot in terms
  of the pressure and putting diesel fuel in it...

They are also given for a minimum viscosity of 5mm²/s which is pretty much the viscosity of diesel fuel at ambient temperature, which is a problem since it is usually heating up with time (return/bypass system)
I can understand the limitation of pumping a liquid with too high a viscosity but I have trouble seeing where it could fail pumping a liquid with too little viscosity.

Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: Contact Bosch-Rexroth and see what they suggest - they have a wide range of pumps...

Comment: Hi Solar Mike, will do!